# Add Datacenter existing cluster

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cassandra-3.0

I try to add a dc to my existing cluster. I changed my networkTopologie with one keyspaces but new DC works like full replica. I only change one keyspace topologie but other keyspaces' rows goes to new DC. When ı add a insert something my existing cluster, these goes to new DC also.

other problem when ı add new DC to my cluster ı lost my superuser which ı use to connect cassandra.

my steps;

on Existing Nodes;

1. Change `cassandra-rackdc.properties` to:

```
dc=datacenter1
rack=rack1
```

2. Change cassandra.yaml `snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch`
3. Rolling restart of nodes: `nodetool flush && nodetool drain && service cassandra stop`
4. Update application specific keyspaces to use NetworkTopology w/ only existing DC
5. `ALTER KEYSPACE {keyspace} WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter1': '3'} AND durable_writes = true;`

new datacenter;

1. Create new instances and install cassandra on all nodes, don't start service
2. Elect single node as DC's seed
3. Update `cassandra.yaml` to all the same settings include `cluster_name` etc... and optimized settings and set seed of all but on to the elected DC seed
   On elected seed set `cassandra.yaml` seeds to 1-2 IPs in datacenter1 (existing)
4. Change cassandra-rackdc.properties to:

```
dc=datacenter2
rack=rack1
```

5. Start service on elected DC seed node
6. Check `nodetool status` that new node joins correctly in cassandra
7. Start other nodes 1-by-1 w/ 2mins between each start

existing cluster:

change keyspace topologie

```
ALTER KEYSPACE {keyspace} 
  WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 
     'datacenter1': '3', 'cassandra': '3'} 
  AND durable_writes = true;
```

keyspace schema;

```
        system_auth |           True | {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter1': '1', 'datacenter2': '1'}
      system_schema |           True |                                                   {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.LocalStrategy'}
                msg |           True |                       {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'}
              event |           True |                     {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter1': '1'}
 system_distributed |           True | {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter1': '1', 'datacenter2': '1'}
             system |           True |                                                   {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.LocalStrategy'}
      system_traces |           True | {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter1': '1', 'datacenter2': '1'}
```

```
Datacenter: datacenter1

=======================
Status=Up/Down

|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID    
                           Rack
UN  xxxxxx   230.49 KiB  256          ?       6a31597c-a86f-4e01-8f59-425d4f96f5fd  rack1
UN  yyyyyy   342.55 KiB  256          ?       bdc1eb13-9707-4a5f-83f0-1cbfafbc520f  rack1

Datacenter: datacenter2

=======================
Status=Up/Down

|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving

--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  zzzzzzzz   273.42 KiB  256          ?       cc56b7d5-15b7-4744-91f5-2ae2e6ac3a8e  rack1
UN  tttttttt  281.71 KiB  256          ?       4682ed50-7189-4903-8ed5-7c9bbdb09811  rack1
```

Note: Non-system keyspaces don't have the same replication settings, effective ownership information is meaningless

Comment: "I only change one keyspace topologie but other keyspaces' rows goes to new DC. When ı add a insert something my existing cluster, these goes to new DC also." How did you know that data is going to other DC. Did you turn on "tracing" and see if other DC's nodes are involved in retrieving data? you can check the ownership of keyspace by using "nodetool status <name of keyspace>" this shows which node has how much percent of data

Comment: ı have only two keyspace first is msg other is event. event topology is NetworkTopologyStrategy and datacenter 1 and datacenter 2 . msg keyspace simpleStrategy and datacenter1 . But when ı insert a row from existing cluster, ı can see this row from my new Datacenter and also cassandra create a msg directory under cassandra DATA directory. nodetool status msg shows two datacenter informations

Comment: Can I see the output of the nodetool status msg? It should show information about two DC's but under "owns" it shows 0.0 for each node in  datacenter2.

Comment: ./nodetool status msg
Datacenter: datacenter1

|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.34.166.51   279.87 KiB  256          32.4%             be697f8f-974a-404f-8bd6-1b0206bde173  rack1
UN  10.34.167.52   342.45 KiB  256          32.5%             f1b0c631-48f5-431c-91e7-3d7e7ef29b99  rack1
UN  10.34.167.53   274.92 KiB  256          33.3%             8905a972-5db0-4e6f-af22-3cf6e5d795f7  rack1

Comment: Datacenter: datacenter2
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.34.166.22   182.84 KiB  256          33.2%             e9177e05-51c8-4535-8cf4-b9849d18c91f  rack1
UN  10.34.166.21   193.34 KiB  256          33.0%             5b9231ad-e300-4d81-a024-ae355fe1c2e6  rack1
UN  10.34.167.111  352.09 KiB  256          35.6%             993683f5-eac5-40dc-a57e-d6126a3c1852  rack1

Answer (score 0):

There is a detailed process described [here](https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2019/02/26/data-center-switch.html) please go through.

TDLR, process contains these steps

1. Change all the keyspaces to use NTS except for the ones with LocalStrategy
2. Start the new nodes with seed nodes config that include other DC seed nodes
3. Alter keyspaces to add new DC
4. Do run `nodetool rebuild <old_dc_name>` on all the new nodes
5. Change client to use new DC if required